# Would a car consume less fuel if Earth's gravitational force was weaker?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, friction

Consider any other variables unchanged (the surface of the road, how the car is driven, wind, etc.), only consider a weaker gravity. How will that affect fuel consumption?

Comment: What about the density of air? It is also a consequence of earth’s gravity. Also, this question is probably better suited for [worldbuilding.se] (you still need to elaborate your scenario in more detail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I have read in the past, and based on gathering actual data, a modern automobile with a reasonable drag coefficient (relatively streamlined) will experience approximately 50% rolling resistance and 50% air drag at normal highway speeds (approximately 60 mph or 95 kph).  Since a major contributor to rolling resistance involves flexing of tire sidewalls as the tires rotate, a weaker force of gravity will put less weight on the tires, and let them flex less, leading to lower rolling resistance and increased fuel economy.  The same effect can be achieved by installing high pressure tires on the automobile, and inflating the tires to 200-300 psi (e.g., airplane tires), as the reduced flexing of the tire sidewalls again leads to increased fuel economy.

Downside of reduced gravity: friction force on the road is directly affected by the weight of the car on the tires.  For lower weight on the tires, the friction force between the car's tires and the road can be expected to go down.

Comment: Why is reduced friction a downside for fuel economy?

Comment: It's not ... but reduced friction leads to safety issues on turns.

Answer (score 1):

The car would spend less fuel.

This is because , as you know, dynamic friction is proportional to the normal force the ground exerts on the car.

This normal force needs to mantain the car in the plane of the road, equilibrating its weight.

Because of this, normal force, and by extention fiction, are directly proportional to the car's weight.

Since the gravitational force is weaker, the weight of the car is also weaker, and so is friction, so you would spend less fuel while driving, since the friction on the car would be smaller.

Answer (score -1):

A weaker gravity would cause a weaker normal force, which causes the friction to be less.And as a result, less fuel is required.

Now, in Newton's 2nd law, the net force on a car moving foreword = $F(fuel)$- $f$(friction).

So, decreasing the effect of friction makes the net force larger and the car can go faster.

And to have the same net force ( same acceleration) ,for example : on the earth and on the moon, we would need less fuel force on the moon than that we need on the earth.

Comment: Why does this answer have two downvotes?  The answer seems fine

Comment: I do not know why!! Maybe because I ignored the effect of drag force, however, the question is about the gravity effect only!

Comment: I think now I understand after reading the top answer. It's because you didn't clarify about the rolling friction that is dependent on the shape of the wheel which is in turn affected by the weight.